# Expo Android Deep linking

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, expo

I have created standalone android app. I downloaded apk and install it. When I send sms with to open app with Deep linking.

link is not clickable its simple text.

Why in my SMS link is not clickable.

For deep linking, is it necessary to upload app on play store?

Comment: Most probably it's not openable due to your SMS app not recognising 'yourapp://' (or exp://) as a valid protocol and doesn't parse it as one. You could you try copying it in a web browser and it shoud open expo or your app

Comment: I have tried in browser as well but Its not opening app